# Laravel: Controller send to C

Tags: c, laravel, architecture

I'm not that experimented in software architecture, so sorry in advance if my question seems strange or simply dumb. (Or if it is the wrong forum ...)

We have a webserver working great with the Laravel framework but we will need to proceed to advanced mathematics functions. We also have a program written in C (on another, more powerful, machine) which can manage this kind of calculation.

And I'm wondering how can I pass data from a controller of laravel to this program. Is there any protocol that should be favored?

Or should we create an API in the C program and make the call from Laravel?

What seems the best option for this scenario?

Comment: Your question leads me only to more questions. Can you provide more details?

Comment: Use Json or xml

Comment: Wrap an API around the C program within that machine to expose functionality and call on the program using something like [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). This probably means a separate Laravel(?) project hosted on the machine that has the C program

Comment: @apokryfos Isn't more useful to use `fastcgi` to call the C program directly. By using this I guess we skip the task of creating an API?

Comment: It really depends if your program just accepts a simple input and spits out a usable output. If things get more complicated then some wrapping around to process input and output will be need to be done anyway so why not an API

Comment: @apokryfos And by creating an API it become also possible to communicate with distant computer. Good idea. If you can answer instead of a comment, I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things of note:

Running C programs to perform tasks is something that PHP actually does all the time when interacting with the OS so this is really a much more common usage scenario.

The major problem here however comes from the fact that the C program is located remotely. You will need some sort of web-server to send requests to it and retrieve the responses.

Calling the program directly is actually possible by using CGI (and by extension FastCGI) but here's the problem. Personally I find the idea that the whole world can directly call a C program hosted on my server a bit unnerving. If you want to secure the program without getting any wrapper around it then you need to modify the program itself to basically act as an API. While this is not unheard of, it will just make your life harder considering there are solutions for building APIs already available.

Another thing to note is that in modern setups PHP itself is actually running on FastCGI so it's really fast especially when coupled with OpCache. I mention this in case speed was the concern for avoiding making a PHP API.

So the suggestion is to use Laravel hosted on the remote machine as an API.

Here's how an example app could work:

**api.php**

```
Route::get("/calculate", function (Request $request) {
     // Transform the request params in a usable format
     // Important is to sanitise and validate the input
     $result = exec("/path/to/my/executable ".escapeshellarg($argument)); //Do escape shell args. It probably isn't enough to ensure security on its own but it helps
     return response()->json([ "result" => $result ]);
});
```

By default Laravel does rate-limit API requests but you can change this in the `Kernel.php`  (if this is a computationally heavy operation then you might want to do this anyway).

You also have options to use Basic authentication or token authentication or basically anything else Laravel ships with.

Note: NodeJS is also very good at doing these things so if you want more options you can look into making a simple node app that does this as well.